# How to get the value of the gas propane in % using MQ2 gas sensor and Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, raspberry-pi, sensors

I am using the following code in python for my MQ2 gas Sensor and ADS1115 as ADC:

```
import time
from gas_detection import GasDetection

def main():
    """Handle example."""

    print('Calibrating ...')
    detection = GasDetection()

    try:
        while True:
            ppm = detection.percentage()
            print('PROPANE: {} ppm'.format(ppm[detection.PROPANE_GAS]))
            time.sleep(0.25)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nAborted by user!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How to get the value of ppm PROPANE_GAS in %?

Comment: `1ppm = 0.0001%` so `PROPANE_GAS_IN_PERECENT = ppm[detection.PROPANE_GAS]/10000`

Comment: for you it would be `print('PROPANE: {} %'.format(ppm[detection.PROPANE_GAS]/10000))`

Comment: if the value was 0.02783714062452509 when reading the analog values, how can I limit the this value to 0.027 for example in python? I tried to use: round(gas_level,2) which must print 0.02 but it doesn't work. ( gas_level is responsible for displaying the analog values)

Comment: `round(gas_level,3)` should work, and btw round off your value is `0.028`, did you get any errors while converting it?

Comment: I tried to do this print('PROPANE: {} %'.format(ppm[detection.PROPANE_GAS]/10000)), I'm getting the following results: 1.6648316512604043e-06. How can I limit this value to just 1.66 for example?